# Why is list.extend appending in this situation?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am using the callback component of multiprocessing.Pool like so:

```
def foo(x):
    err = []
    return err

errors = []
res = pool.map_async(foo, mylist, callback=errors.extend)

print errors
```

And I get:

```
[[]]
```

If I append a test error to err inside of foo(), I get this:

```
[['test']]
```

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Why doesn't it mirror this behavior:

```
a = []
b = []
a.extend(b)
print a
```

Results:

```
[]
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. When I run the code at the top (with a little added boilerplate to make it work), I get an empty list as the result. I get this in both Python 3.6 (after changing the `print` call) and in 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment, so I post an answer.
pool.map_async will return a **list**, call it Result.
Your callback function apply to this Result.In your case, Result is [[err0], [err1], ...], so error.extend(Result) get [[]].
Try this:

```
def foo(x):
    err = something
    return err

errors = []
res = pool.map_async(foo, mylist, callback=errors.extend)
# or
# res.wait()
# print res.get()
print errors
```